# How to specify return type as return type of another methods in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, python-asyncio

I have a helper class for scraping paginated content.

The classes that inherit from this class in simplification just implements the extract_info method.

I want to give the correct return type of get_from_few_pages method - Async generator that yields values of the type which is return type of extract_information method

How can I do it?

P.S I couldn't find how to declare the type as a return of some function/method.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or solutions

```
class PaginatedContent():

@classmethod
def extract_information(cls, page: HtmlElement):
    """Extracting information from one page """

async def _get_page(self, page: int) -> HtmlElement:
    """Just requesting a page"""
    async with self._get_session().get(**Some url**) as page:
        return lxml.html.document_fromstring(await page.text())

async def extract_data_from_page(
    self, page_number: int
):
    """Requesting and extracting information"""
    return self.extract_information(await self._get_page(page_number))

async def get_from_few_pages(
    self, max_pages: int
):
    """Requesting and extracting information from few pages"""
    pages = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(
            asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(self.extract_data_from_page(i))
        )
        for i in range(max_pages)
    ]

    for coroutine in pages:
        await asyncio.gather(coroutine)
        yield coroutine.result()
```

Example of the inelegant current solution - still looking for sth better

```
def get_from_few_pages(
    self, max_pages: int = 0, pages_to_scrape_generator=lambda x: range(2, x + 1)
) -> AsyncGenerator[Generator[_AlbumInfo], None]:
    ...
```

Comment: Give mypy reveal_locals a try. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#displaying-the-type-of-an-expression. There is also typing.AsyncGenerator.

Comment: Yes, I know there is an AsyncGenerator typing but I don't know what argument should I pass to it

Comment: Just by simply looking at it I would say that it's AsyncGenerator[>>result of extract_data_from_page<<, None]. So, your yield type is whatever returned by extract_data_from_page after resolving which looks like some kind of page object. Your send type is None, since nothing is being sent to this generator.

Comment: The Result of extract_data_from_page differs depending on every class that inherits from PaginatedContent, and it never is HtmlElement. Can I accomplish this without specifying a return type of get_from_few_pages on every class that inherits from PaginatedContent

Comment: Would it be possible to declare a return type as a class variable and then yield that type? For example, Class Foo declares _YieldType = FooType class variable. And then get_from_few_pages has AsyncGenerator[self._YieldType, None]. Then any class that inherits Foo defines their own _YieldType. Would this even work? I'm not sure if there is another way without resorting to Any or doing some kind of overloading which is what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: When I try to do add type to init and pass it from child classes I get the error: Unresolved reference 'self'